# How to set part of string to bold font to TextView on iphone

Tags: iphone, objective-c, textview, uifont

how to set part of text of the textview to bold font on iPhone?

Comment: Do you want a part or complete text in bold font??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use NSAttributedString... Here is a sample UIController to draw NSAttributedString https://github.com/AliSoftware/Ali-Cocoa-Classes

Answer (score 2):

You can't use UITextView for rich text, have a look at [CoreText](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/StringsTextFonts/Conceptual/CoreText_Programming/Introduction/Introduction.html) and [NSAttributedString](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSAttributedString_Class/Reference/Reference.html).